# GraphQL schema related query returning null

Tags: javascript, json, express, graphql, schema

I'm learning GraphQL and cannot understand why this query's `name` and `description` is returning null data? Am I doing something wrong, or maybe have a typo somewhere?

db.json (using `json-server` to hold backend data temporarily)

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "23",
            "firstName": "Chun-li",
            "age": 32,
            "companyId": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "40",
            "firstName": "E.Honda",
            "age": 45,
            "companyId": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstName": "Sagat",
            "age": 45,
            "companyId": "2"
        }
    ],
    "companies": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Apple",
            "description": "iphone"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Google",
            "description": "search"
        }
    ]
}
```

server.js (using express middleware)

```
import express from 'express'
import expressGraphQL from 'express-graphql'
import {
    schema
} from './schema/schema'

const app = express()

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
}))

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('server is listening')
})
```

schema.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLSchema,
} from 'graphql'

const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Company',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        name: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        description: {
            type: GraphQLString
        }
    }
})

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        firstName: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        age: {
            type: GraphQLInt
        },
        company: {
            type: CompanyType,
            async resolve(parentValue, args) {
                console.log({
                    parentValue,
                    args
                })
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${parentValue.companyId}`)
                    console.log(response)
                    return response.data
                } catch (error) {
                    return console.log(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: GraphQLString
                }
            },
            async resolve(parentValue, args) {
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/users/${args.id}`)
                    return response.data
                } catch (error) {
                    return console.log(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

export const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
})
```

My query;

[image: GraphiQL query]

Comment: Your company resolver on user is fetching data from the user endpoint not the companies endpoint.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something dumb lol...